# preg_replace multiple Youtube links in Single Variable

Tags: php, youtube, preg-replace, regex-group

I'm still learning PHP and have never touched regex or preg_replace before today so please forgive my ignorance. I'm modifying a script for my forums to convert YouTube links in posts to embed code. So far if the string only contains the single link it works, but when I have multiple links in multiple posts it doesn't. Furthermore, I'm not sure how the $text variable is populated because it's not just a single string and contains all the status posts for the user in one variable which is passed to other functions. Any assistance is much appreciated.

It looks like one string:

```
echo "$text";
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rb47k3KHtQtesttesthttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ah2rSAdZljMhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ah2rSAdZljM
```

But in fact it is multiple strings in one variable. This has me confused as I don't know how this is done without arrays and I would very much like to know.

```
var_dump($text);
string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rb47k3KHtQ" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ah2rSAdZljM" string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ah2rSAdZljM"
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$search = '/(https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch.v=[a-z0-9]{8,11})/i';

$replace = '<iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
$replace .= $1;
$replace .= '"></iframe>';

echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
?>
```

With the $1 the script doesn't work unless I shorten the text to remove all other links. I need to be able to replace all of the links but I don't know how to access the regex groups except for the standard $1, $2, $3, etc. from tutorials I've been following. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: For anyone following this and trying to do the same, Will Hines' answer pointed in the right direction but I still had to adjust the regex and group match. My regex was matching the entire video url as one group so the embed src was basically:
    `https://www.youtube.com/embed/https://......`

To fix this I changed the regex to:
   `/(https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch.v=)([a-z0-9]{8,11})/i`

and the match from `"\$1"` to `"\$2"`, this replaces only the video ID after watch?v=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me if I change this

```
$replace .= $1;
```

to this

```
$replace .= "\$1";
```